# Charter font shape undefined with LuaLaTeX

Tags: fonts, luatex, font-encodings

I have to use a publisher style ([link](https://github.com/programming-journal/programming)) and I have problems with the basic example. I am using LuaTeX as suggested. The same happens with XeTeX, but not with pdfTeX.

Here is a MWE, extracted from the provided template:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[charter]{mathdesign}
\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

Problem:

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `TU/mdbch/m/n' undefined
(Font)              using `TU/lmr/m/n' instead on input line 105.
```

Is there something I can do, or this font is simply not available in this setting? If so, what would be the best thing to do, ask the template authors? I am saying this because I would expect the provided example to work flawlessly, at least in the recommended setting (LuaTeX).

My understanding is that `/m/n` is not some weird combination that does not work but rather the "normal" font, and that the problem is in the encoding (`TU`), but I don't know much about this stuff.

Comment: I am the creator of the style. Can you please give me the version info of the class file you are using?

Comment: @Tobias latest release, version 1.2.

Comment: Note: 1.3a is a pre-release now, here: https://github.com/programming-journal/programming/releases/tag/v1.3a

Comment: @Tobias I confirm it is fixed in 1.3a, good!

Comment: I got the same problem here ... > \usepackage[bitstream-charter]{mathdesign} leads to an error: > Font shape `TU/mdput/m/n' undefined(Font) using `TU/lmr/m/n' instead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default output font encoding with LuaLaTeX is `TU`, but you want `T1`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[charter]{mathdesign}

\begin{document}

Hello

\end{document}
```

The warning you get when `fontspec` is loaded is spurious and should have no consequence. Loading `fontenc` is not needed and might even lead to bad output.

```
\documentclass{article}

% fix for the spurious warning issued by
\DeclareFontFamily{TU}{mdbch}{}
\DeclareFontShape{TU}{mdbch}{m}{n}{
 <-> \UnicodeFontFile{lmroman10-regular}{\UnicodeFontTeXLigatures}
}{}

\usepackage[charter]{mathdesign}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{XCharter}

\begin{document}

Hello

\end{document}
```

Comment: The package `fontenc` is already loaded in the style I am trying to use as `\RequirePackage[LGR,OT1,LY1,T1]{fontenc}`. Indeed, if I add either this command or what you suggest to the MWE, the problem is solved. But then I don't understand what is the problem with the style file... which you can find [here](https://github.com/programming-journal/programming/blob/master/programming.cls).

Comment: I took a closer look to the style: it also loads package `fontspec`, and it does it *after* loading `fontenc`. Indeed, if I add `fontspec` after `fontenc` in your example the error comes back, but not if I swap the order... is it expected? Should one be loaded after the other? Can't find any doc about this...

Comment: @effeffe I added a workaround

Answer (score 1):

In the latest version of the style file, there is a different workaround for the problem. It turns out that not all fonts or packages are not yet ready for the `TU` encoding. In this case, everything works fine with the `EU` encoding, hence, for the time being, [`EU` encoding is being forced for `fontspec`](https://github.com/programming-journal/programming/commit/390a7c88d34af2aec43576ffc95e485859ef5cb0)

The workaround used but for the current version would entail the following:

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{euenc}{fontspec}
\documentclass[english,submission]{programming}

%...
```

The variant by @egreg seems correct when using the `TU` encoding, but I'd rather wait for the `XCharter` package to be actually compatible with `TU`.

*edit:* Disclaimer: I am the author of the style.